# ListBox of ListBoxes bound to Collection of Collections

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm

I am trying to bind a property `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Location>>` to a ListBox with ItemTemplate of ListBox which in-turn has an ItemTemplate that is a grid.  The layout of the listbox within a listbox seems to work fine. However, I am having issues with my databinding.

For the second layer listbox ItemsSource I have tried binding using the Collection Current Item Bindings `ItemSource="{Binding /}"` and using `ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding /}"`.  I new to WPF and am using MVVM, so any tips and/or criticism are appreciated.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="4" Width="610" Height="600" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentLocation.Children}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox Width="550" Height="100" Margin="5"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  ItemsSource="{Binding /}" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Text="Name:" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Text="Description:" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding TODO}">
                                <TextBlock Text="Edit"/>
                            </Button>
                            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding TODO}">
                                <TextBlock Text="Delete"/>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Why do you require a ListBox containing ListBoxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `ListBoxItem` contains the `DataContext` of whatever the object is in the parent collection, so you should be fine to specify nothing in the Binding.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionOfCollections}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- DataContext of each item will an inner ObservableCollection<Location> -->
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding }" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Ahh, yes. I had it stuck in my head that I needed to go down one more level to get to that 2nd list. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

The correct notation for binding to the current `DataContext` as a whole is `{Binding}`.

```
<ListBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentLocation.Children}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
                            <!-- snip -->
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I think Rachel beat you to it. Thank you though!

Comment: No, I was about 28 seconds faster (and just discovered yet another useful feature on this site)... But this time I'll let her get away with it ;)

Comment: @Tobias You were 28 seconds faster than me, so +1 from me :) I think I would have been faster if I had just posted the code sample, but I wanted to include an explanation of why the bindings worked, so had to think a minute.

Comment: Haha, would you like me to change it.  I thought it was ordering the answers in descending order.

Comment: It's fine. I'm not here for the reputation but to help others. And it orders the answers by `(Answer ? 1 : 0), Votes, Random.Next()` ;)